# Remove last character in a list

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, c#-4.0

I am building a list from a dataset as 12345_9876,125675_0987,

I try to remove the last `,`  from the list like we do for strings..

```
value.TrimEnd(',');
```

Can we do similar thing for a list?

Comment: I'm confused...You want to remove the last element of a list? Or you want to remove the comma from the string in the last element of a list? If that's it, why are the commas there in the first place?

Comment: I want to remove the last comma in my list

Comment: foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
                {
                    list.Add(row["Nerk"] + "_" + row["Acty"]+",");
                }

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but it seems to me like whatever it is, you will benefit from making yourself familiar with [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y7h14879.aspx) and [String.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd783876.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use String.Join:

```
String delimitedList = String.Join(",", yourList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Think you just want this?:

```
  List<string mylistfromdataset = // I dunno how you populated it
  var newlist = mylistfromdataset.Select(x=> x.TrimEnd(',')).ToList();
```

**EDIT** after the poster cleared the question, you could use this 2 line code to make a new list where the last string the , is trimmed.

```
   var list = listofstring.Take(listofstring.Count - 1).ToList();
   list.Add(listofstring.Last().TrimEnd(','));
```

(Make a list excluding the last item. then trim the last item with , at the end and at it to the new list.)

Comment: ListOfString needs to be your List<string> var :)

Comment: And you ll need the System.Linq namespace I guess so you can get the extension method .Select()

Comment: foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
                {
                    list.Add(row["Nerk"] + "_" + row["Acty"]+",");
                }

Comment: Still its removing comma(,) for each element end in a list

Comment: I just want the comma to be removed at the end of the last element in a list

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you?

```
var lastElement = yourList.ElementAt<string>(yourList.Count - 1).TrimEnd(',');
yourList.RemoveAt(yourList.Count - 1);
yourList.Insert(yourList.Count,lastElement);
```

Comment: so you coppied my answer 100% ... ?

Comment: Sorry..I thought its a default class...will try this...thansk alot

Comment: But this is trimming comma(,) for each item at the end,I want to trim only the last item comma(,)...since i have to send the data as  1234_234,3456_987,2345_098

Comment: @Maximc your and mine answers were similar

Comment: @user1046415 hope this will fix your problem

Comment: @nsconnector, orly it was 100% the same you only changed the var name ... why double answer ...

Comment: @Maximc sorry but i was trying out to solve it from what i understood...i just posted my effort but unfortunately it matched your answer..that's it

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=value.LastIndexOf(",");
if(i!=-1) 
   value=value.Remove(i,1);
```